# requireJS - parameter substitution

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

How should I get this to work ?

```
var param = 'someFunction';

require('views/MyView').[param]();
```

When I run this code, I get the following error

```
SyntaxError: missing name after . operator
require('views/MyView').[renderMethod]();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.` and `[]` are kind of the same thing.

What you want is `require('views/MyView')[renderMethod]();`

`require(...)` will return the exported module, which should basically be an object with the functions as properties.

So, let's say we have:

```
var obj = {
   foo: function() { alert('foo'); }
   bar: function() { alert('bar'); }
}
```

Then you could do:

`obj.foo();` - call a fixed name function

`obj['foo']();` - dynamic name fixed arguments

`obj['foo'].apply(this, args)` - dynamic function name and arguments.

Edit:

One more thing I noticed:

In requirejs, when you do something like this:

```
define (require, function() {
    x = require('views/Foo');
    x.bar();
}
```

RequireJS will determine by parsing the code that you will need the 'view/Foo' module, and make sure it is loaded before executing your code.

But if you want to load a dynamic module, it won't know beforehand what module to preload, so you will have to use a callback to be notified when your module will be loaded:

```
define (require, function() {

    require('views/' + viewName, function(myView) {
        myView.bar(); // or 
        myView[dynamicFunc](); // ... 
    });
}
```